# django - dealing with windows line endings when doing max_length form validation

Tags: django, validation, line-endings

Because windows line ending are actually two characters (`\r\n`), max_length treats them as two characters. I want them to only be treated as one character.

What would be the best way to deal with this? I assume it would be best to convert the line endings, but where in the process would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to convert the line endings by overriding the form's `clean_<fieldname>()` method, or the more general `clean()` method. Before cleaning the data, Django will convert it to Python and validate it, so you'll also need to move the max_length validation into the overridden clean method. Also note that, "this method should return the cleaned data, regardless of whether it changed anything or not."

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

In your case, the code would look like this:

```
from django import forms
from string import replace

class YourForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField()
    # Your fields here

    def clean_some_field(self):
        max_length = 50
        data = self.cleaned_data["some_field"]
        data = replace(data, "\r", "")
        if len(data) > max_length:
            raise forms.ValidationError("some_field is too long!")
        return data
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! I'm struggling a bit though. The field gets cleaned, but validation is happening on the raw data. Should running `form.is_valid()` run validation on the form after all the fields have been cleaned? Or do I need to run `is_valid()` on something else?

Comment: The problem is that `clean_<fieldname>()` is run after validation of things such as `max_length`. This means you have to do the validation of the length in `clean_<fieldname>()` and get rid of `max_length` from your field. Maybe you could update your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914123/django-how-to-process-clean-a-field-before-validation

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. I'll update the answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can I use super to keep all the other validators? If so, do I place the data back in `self.cleaned_data['some_field']`?