# django - how to process/clean a field before validation

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a form that needs to be validated only after it has been cleaned.

What happens when you run `form.is_valid()` ? Is the form cleaned and then that cleaned version of the form validated?

The behaviour I'm getting at the moment, is that if my field does not pass validation before cleaning, even if cleaning would make it pass, `is_valid()` returns `False`.

Am I doing something wrong?

### Code:

```
# View
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=5)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']
        return message.replace('a', '') # remove all "a"s from message

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/on_success/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/on_failure/')
```

I want `form.is_valid()` to return `True` if the message has less than 5 characters **NOT** including `a`!

Is it possible to run `clean_<fieldname>()` after `to_python()` but before `run_validators()`? Or should I be doing this some other way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think the process of form validation (and its correct order) is really [well documented](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation).

Would you mind sharing your code? There is a `clean` method on every formfield, responsible for running `to_python`, `validate` and `run_validators` (in this order). `to_python` accepts the raw value of the widget, coercing it into a python type, `validate`  takes the coerced value and runs field-specific validation.

**Answer updated with regards to the code given**

`clean_message` is called after all the other validation has run like `to_python`, `validate` and, most importantly, `run_validators`. I think the last method will check the that the `max_length` constraint isn't violated. So you changing the data afterwards has no affect.

The solution is to raise a `ValidationError` here. Removing `max_length` will avoid any validation on the input's length.

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']
        message = message.replace('a', '') # remove all "a"s from message
        if len(message) >= 5:
            raise ValidationError('Too many characters ...')
        return message
```

Comment: I've added some simplified code showing what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How will raising a new error stop the current error from being raised? `Edit:` Oh right, then I can remove `max_length` from the field! Right?

Comment: @Acorn Yeah, you can remove it. I thought is was required, but that applied to models.

Comment: So the gist of it. I need to do my validation in my `clean_<fieldname>()` instead of using `max_length`

Answer (score 2):

As an extra, when `is_valid()` return `False`, you can check why, printing `self.errors` inside the form.

if you watch the `is_valid()` code, this checks the form `is_bound` and the `self.errors` is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite CharField:

```
class CustomCharField(forms.CharField):
    def clean(self, value):
        return super().clean(value.replace('a', ''))
```

Then you can use it in form

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    message = CustomCharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just adding to Reiner Gerecke.

When the is_valid() method is called on the form, the MultiEmailField.clean() method will be run as part of the cleaning process and it will, in turn, call the custom to_python() and validate() methods.
[Just read the "Form field default cleaning" part and its example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning)