# Parsing a Datetime String into a Django DateTimeField

Tags: django, datetime, format

I have a Django app with a model that contains a field of type DateTimeField.
I am pulling data from the web in the format of `2008-04-10 11:47:58-05`.
I believe that the last 3 characters in this example are the timezone.
How can I preserve that data in the DateTimeField, and is there an easy conversion between the two? Setting the DateTimeField to simply contain a string of the above format throws a ValidationError.

Thank you!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('2008-04-10 11:47:58-05')
```

Which returns a datetime (that can be assigned to the DateTimeField).

Comment: this sounds great, but in my python 2.6.5 there is no datetime.parser or datetime.datetime.parser modules (I get an ImportError). What am I missing?

Comment: Note that `dateutil` is a third-party module (see [python-dateutil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) on PyPI), which you may not have installed by default.

Comment: perfect, thanks!  It figured out my string date format, great time saver.

Comment: How can i parse the 'November 1, 1990' to date sir i am new to python?

Answer (score 109):

You can also use [Django's implementation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse). I would in fact prefer it and only use something else, if Django's parser cannot handle the format.

For example:

```
>>> from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
>>> parse_datetime('2016-10-03T19:00:00')
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 19, 0)
>>> parse_datetime('2016-10-03T19:00:00+0200')
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 19, 0, tzinfo=<django.utils.timezone.FixedOffset object at 0x8072546d8>)
```

To have it converted to the right timezone when none is known, use make_aware from `django.utils.timezone`.

So ultimately, your parser utility would be:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
from django.utils.timezone import is_aware, make_aware

def get_aware_datetime(date_str):
    ret = parse_datetime(date_str)
    if not is_aware(ret):
        ret = make_aware(ret)
    return ret
```

Comment: I sure wish the docs specified exactly what a 'well formatted' date is, though! I would expect that to mean RFC 1123, but it doesn't seem to like what my browser is sending back...

Comment: This answer is not correct in that a timezone aware datetime is not returned, at least not in 1.8.4. You can try this for yourself
`from django.utils import timezone, dateparse;  timezone.is_aware(dateparse.parse_datetime('2015-09-04 19:22:17'))`
and also see in the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/utils/dateparse/#parse_datetime) that a datetime.datetime is returned.

Comment: @TheCardCheat You're right that it doesn't make_aware() (github tells me it never did and yet code I used became aware somewhere). But, if an input string contains a timezone offset that is recognized then it *does* return an aware datetime.

Answer (score 18):

I've been using this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
from datetime import datetime
tz = get_current_timezone()
dt = tz.localize(datetime.strptime(str_date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Answer (score 7):

String format of Django DateTimeField is "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ".
Hence, conversion  between eachother can be done  using strptime() or strptime() using this format.

eg. for string formatted value  (2016-10-03T19:00:00.999Z), it can be converted
to Django datetime object as :

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '2016-10-03T19:00:00.999Z'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Django Forms, you can specify `input_formats` to your `DateField`. See the [DateField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/fields/#datefield)

If you are wanting to parse *arbitrary* date information, you could use something like [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) and implement a method that Django calls to do the parsing before it hits the validators. (See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914205/224334) for a good summary of how validations work and when to insert them)

Answer (score 3):

To make standard format:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
formatted_datetime = parse_datetime(YOUR_STRING_DATETIME).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(f"formatted_datetime: {formatted_datetime}")
```

You will see something like this:

```
2022-02-09 12:58:52
```

Be successful