# Django string to date format

Tags: python, django, datetime

I want to convert my string date to django date format. I tried a method. but did not work.

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('date'),"Y-mm-dd").date()
```

I got this error.

```
time data '2014-04-07' does not match format 'Y-mm-dd'
```

what 's wrong in my code.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It should be `%Y-%m-%d`:

```
>>> s = "2014-04-07"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
datetime.date(2014, 4, 7)
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

- `%Y` stands for a year with century as a decimal number
- `%m` - month as a zero-padded decimal number
- `%d` - day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number

Comment: I have a string date with timezone which is giving me an error when converting: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: T18:30:00.000Z`

How can I convert this string date: `2019-10-15T18:30:00.000Z`?

Comment: @saran3h you can use django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime for that. Check Melvyn's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636760/parsing-a-datetime-string-into-a-django-datetimefield

Answer (score 37):

It might be convenient to use django's [dateparse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse) in this case.

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_date
date_str = request.POST.get('date')
date = parse_date(date_str)
```

Comment: `parse_date` not working as espected and returns `None` if date not in `%Y-%m-%d` format.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, `parse_datetime` worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

`django.utils.dateparse.parse_date` function will return `None` if given date not in `%Y-%m-%d` format

I have not found a function in django source code to parse string by `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`. So I wrote a custom helper function for that and 
 I have added to here for help others.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.formats import get_format

def parse_date(date_str):
    """Parse date from string by DATE_INPUT_FORMATS of current language"""
    for item in get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date_str, item).date()
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            continue

    return None
```

Comment: Awesome! if have few different formats, the answer is excellent!

Comment: Some strings may be accepted wrongly by multiple formats. 04-07-2021 or 07-04-2021?

Comment: @PedroLacerda yes, if your `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`  includes these formats both, it works buggy. I think you should not use both formats.

Answer (score 7):

It might be convenient to use Django's [dateparse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse)'s parse_datetime in this case. you don't have to explicitly apply the data time format if that is dynamic.

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
date = parse_datetime(datetime_str)
```