# python django subtract time field

Tags: python, django

I have two time `start_time` and `end_time`.

For start time I am getting `6:30` and for end_time I am getting `7:30`.
Now i want to subtract the time only. i am getting this from html text field.

How can I subtract this two time fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try converting these to `time objects` first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918095/django-string-to-date-format

Comment: `end_time - start_time`?

Comment: like i said I am getting it from html text field so end_time - start_time wont work

Comment: Then you don't have two "times" you have two strings (by the sounds of it) parse them first. What have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("6:30",'%H:%M')
>>> time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("7:30",'%H:%M')
>>> difference = time2-time1
>>> difference
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
>>> difference.seconds
3600
>>> "{:0>8}".format(datetime.timedelta(seconds=difference.seconds))
'01:00:00'
>>> "{:0>8}".format(datetime.timedelta(seconds=666777))
'7 days, 17:12:57'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s1 = "06:30"
>>> s2 = "07:30"
>>> timeformat = "%I:%M"
>>> delta = datetime.strptime(s2, timeformat) - datetime.strptime(s1, timeformat)
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
>>> delta.seconds
3600
```

`delta` is the time difference. You can check the value and convert accordingly.