# Save date in django in desired format

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I want to save date in my django model into desired format.

```
post_date = str(request.POST['date'])
```

I am getting date from front end is `12/21/2016`
i want to save this date in my django modal is like `21-Dec-2016`.

How can i do it.
it will be good if you can provide some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django string to date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918095/django-string-to-date-format)

Comment: looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876370/django-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

you want to store in DB string parameter? The easiest way [convert input string to date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and then convert from date to string. But of course it is more logical to store date format imho