# Date formator In django

Tags: python, django, django-views

i working on a registration form in django
I taking  input from date field from front end is `"12/15/2016"`
but i want to save it like `12 dec 2016` in my django database.
I am using this calender

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

my `model.py` for date is

```
posting_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
post_date = str(request.POST['date'])

date = post_date.split('/')

formatted_date= date[1]+"-"+date[0]+"-"+date[2]
```

I want to save Dec instead of 12 for month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save date in django in desired format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140317/save-date-in-django-in-desired-format)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
from dateutil import parser
formatted_date = parser.parse("12/15/2016")
yourobject.posting_data = formatted_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting it using strptime and strftime instead:

```
formatted_datetime = datetime.strptime(post_date, strftime('%m/%d/%Y')) #formatted_datetime is now a datetime object
print( formatted_datetime.strftime('%d-%b-%Y') )
```

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: global name 'strftime' is not defined

Comment: from datetime import datetime

Comment: i alreday import this

Comment: It needs to be, in the file:
from datetime import datetime

formatted_datetime = datetime.strptime(post_date, strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format). See also: [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)