# Django: How can I filter a user input date with a DateTimeField DB in Django passing the filter options as dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have search option which user input from front end.

```
search = {"Date":"2016-02-07","Status":"pass" }
```

Then I am mapping with those values with column names in DB.

```
query_to_field_mapping = {"Date": "date","Status": "result"}

query = {query_to_field_mapping[key]: value for key, value in search.items()}
```

Now I have DateTimeField in DB. When I am using filter I am trying with below one:

```
result = Customer.objects.filter(**query)
```

Here am trying to filter as per date field & want to get the filtered record as well. I tried the same with no success .How can I proceed?

Any help ll be awesome!!!

I tried the some other question from SO: [How can I filter a date of a DateTimeField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django)

I couldn't get a way to solve my problem as there we are passing a column name 1 by 1 .But right now I am passing as dictionary.

Comment: "I tried the same with no success" - what did you try?

Comment: Tried the ORM **result = Customer.objects.filter(**query)**

Comment: Please see [Parsing a Datetime String into a Django DateTimeField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636760/parsing-a-datetime-string-into-a-django-datetimefield). You need to pass a `datetime` object to the query instead of a date string.

Comment: try `query_to_field_mapping = {"Date": "date__contains","Status": "result"}`. Most probably it is because your datetimefield contains values including time, but when you search, you are providing only a date string (without time), therefore a `2016-02-07` (your query param) is not equal to `2016-02-07T12:32:22` (a possible value in the DB)

Comment: @iulian  Thanks a lot. You saved my time. Please answer the question. I will mark as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one. The reason why it doesn't work is because you filter for equality of `datetime` field by providing a `date` string, therefore a `2016-02-07` date (your query param) does not equal `2016-02-07T12:32:22` (a possible value in the DB).

To overcome this situation, use one of the field lookups possibilities from the link of your own question. As a specific example, let's use a `contains` field lookup, like so:

```
query_to_field_mapping = {"Date": "date__contains","Status": "result"}
```

Thus, when passing the `query_to_field_mapping` to `.filter()`, it will look for the date within the datetime that you need.