# how to import date time data from excel into django model（mysql）?

Tags: django

I have a question about django admin import file. my excel data include DateTime data like 2010/10/10 13:10 , i want to import it into mysql by django admin. I used DateTimeField in models. What is the time data format? how to do this?

Comment: check out : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#datetime-format

Comment: yeah, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

that function is natural from python, just stablish the format of incoming string date and do the following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228410/2946222

or

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636887/2946222

Answer (score 0):

[https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.DateTimeWidget][1]

This can work, just use settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS