# How to convert django default timezone to different format

Tags: django

**Time format**

```
"2018-12-13T05:20:06.427Z"
```

django providing time zone in above format when i am fetching data from database using ORM query.

**In my model field is in  below way.**

```
models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True,null=True)
```

How can i convert it into **"24 feb 2018"** like this

Comment: Please checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636760/parsing-a-datetime-string-into-a-django-datetimefield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from @Sosthenes Kwame Boame answer, you can use `strftime` for formatting.

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %b %Y') 

Out[13]: '13 Dec 2018'
```

Instead of passing `datetime` module to `time` variable, you should pass your model field's value.

If you want to learn more about format type then you can visit the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) page.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to display this on the frontend?

You need to do this in your template:

```
{{ object_name.datefield_name|date:'j b Y' }}
```

So you call the datefield and render it with the '|date' tag with a format assigned ':'FORMAT''.

Learn more about the date tag, along with the various formats here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date