# Djano value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

Tags: python, django, date

for example when I use auto_now_add=True "Jan. 1, 2021, 5:05 a.m." format, but when I want to update the date, I get the error "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']", I don't have a problem when I update it by entering in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format, but how can I bring this date automatically in this format?

models.py;

```
class problemduyuru(models.Model):
    olusturulmatarihi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    duyurutipi = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    incidentno = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    baslangiczamani = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    aciklama = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

views.py create and update;

update;

```
def problemduyurusuupdate(request, id):
    problemmember = problemduyuru.objects.get(id=id)
    problemmember.duyurutipi = request.POST['duyurutipi']
    problemmember.incidentno = request.POST['incidentno']
    problemmember.baslangiczamani = request.POST['baslangiczamani']
    problemmember.aciklama = request.POST['aciklama']
    problemmember.olusturulmatarihi = request.POST['olusturulmatarihi']
    problemmember.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Alarmlar was updated successfully!')
    return redirect('/problemduyurusu')
```

create;

```
def problemduyurusucreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        problemmember = problemduyuru(
            duyurutipi=request.POST['dduyurutipi'],
            incidentno=request.POST['dincidentno'],
            baslangiczamani=request.POST['dbaslangiczamani'],
            aciklama=request.POST['daciklama'],
            olusturulmatarihi=request.POST['dolusturulmatarihi'], )
                 
        try:
            problemmember.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            pass
        problemmember.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Alarmlar was created successfully!')
        return redirect('/problemduyurusu')
    else:
        return render(request, 'problemduyurusucreate.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTimeField The field always accepts strings in ISO 8601 formatted dates or similar recognized by parse_datetime(). Some examples are:

- '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
- '2006-10-25T14:30:59'
- '2006-10-25 14:30'
- '2006-10-25T14:30'
- '2006-10-25T14:30Z'
- '2006-10-25T14:30+02:00'
- '2006-10-25'

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

but if you want to bring this date automatically in this format you can use edit it in views.py (update)

```
problemmember.olusturulmatarihi = parse_datetime(request.POST['olusturulmatarihi'])
```

[Parsing a Datetime String into a Django DateTimeField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636760/parsing-a-datetime-string-into-a-django-datetimefield/24228410)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse

and edit template for what format you like to show

```
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: thank u so much, it worked!!! {{ value|date:"D d M Y" }} +1